# Forge- viewer with Three.js giving error objectLoader loader.setPath undefined

Tags: three.js, autodesk-forge, webvr

I have these scripts added in my index.html

```
 <script src="https://developer.api.autodesk.com/modelderivative/v2/viewers/three.min.js?v=v3.2"></script>
<script src="https://developer.api.autodesk.com/modelderivative/v2/viewers/viewer3D.js?v=v3.2"></script>
<script src="https://mamboleoo.be/learnThree/demos/OBJLoader.js"></script>
```

Now when I try to load an obj file to my scene i get error loader.setPath is undefined. Through research I can safely say its regarding Three.js version that I am using and different threads speaks about updating Three.js to newer builds.
BUT if I update Three.js from anyother url than the one stated above. my forge-viewer stops working and give me error on loadModels.

Comment: What version of Threejs are you using? The viewer currently uses R71. If what you are trying to load is an OBJ file, you could do it by translating that OBJ file with the Model Derivative API and load it into the scene of the viewer. Have you looked into that workflow?

Comment: yes I have. im using model derivative API for multiple models. but this is vr oculus controller models which has to be attached with headset in webvr extension.

 <script src="https://developer.api.autodesk.com/modelderivative/v2/viewers/three.min.js?v=v3.2"></script>

this is where im getting Three.js from

Comment: You cannot change the THREE.js version that the viewer is using, but a simple workaround is often to borrow code from a later THREE.js version. It is rather straightforward as long as the implementation hasn't too many dependencies spread around...

Comment: Philippe wrote a log post with the suggestion he gave above, here is the link if you are still looking into this https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/how-add-newest-threejs-features-forge-viewer